# вопрос про CSS в многостраничном сайте

Tags: css

Я делаю сайт с несколькими страницами (контакты, галерея, и т.п) И поскольку это мой первый сайт, у меня вопрос, как стоит поступать, привязывать каждую страницу к тому же css файлу что и index.html или нужно создавать отдельный css файл для каждой новой страницы сайта? (работаю через gulp). Спасибо!

Comment: Все на ваше усмотрение, но обычно CSS не плодят. Одного достаточно. Иногда разделяют логически, например, можно разделить на общие стили и кастомные (в случае с использование нескольких визуальных тем, например, или как-то еще). Иногда разделяют по функционалу. Иногда выделяют стили для мобильной версии. Иногда особенности выносят специфические стили для конкретных версий браузеров (для старых версий IE, например), и т.д.

Comment: Благодарю за отличный ответ!